# Is some amount of color banding expected on LED printers?

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, laser-printer

I just got a new Brother MFC-L3770CDW laser/LED printer and have noticed slight "banding" in large filled areas, where there are horizontal bands (in portrait orientation) across the page in which colors are darker. I've only owned inkjet printers in the past, and I never paid much attention to the print quality of the laser printers I've used at work/school/etc. so I'm not sure if this is expected. These bands are closely spaced and the difference between the light bands and the dark bands is very faint, but noticeable, especially if printing a full-page image.

I know laser printers have a reputation for worse image reproduction than inkjet printers, but I can't tell if this is normal and I'm being overly picky, or if it indicates something wrong with the printer. Here is a test page I found on Brother's website:

[image: Test page from Brother with four colored areas]

And here's what my printer produces:

[image: colorbars-try2.png]

Is this the expected quality of a laser printer?

Answer (score 0):

All printers (inkjets as well as lasers) can be expected to produce some banding. It results from tiny imperfections in the movement of the paper or the rest of the printing mechanism. How much is within spec depends on the printer model. In this case only Brother can tell you.

It should also be noted that this banding will be most visible in large areas of a single colour. In things like photos and most other prints, it should not show up.

Comment: I lived with banding on an HP colour laser for 3 years, only on grey areas. I replaced the black cartridge and now it's gone.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In most colour lasers, the black toner gets to the paper via a circuitous path, so it's rare the cartridge is the problem. In the Brother MFC-L3770CDW the issue could be with a drum - but it's in all colours and 4 faulty drums is *very* unlikely.

Comment: The banding or streaking I referred to was horizontal and repetitive with an interval of a bit less than 1 inch. The HP defect ruler said that 22.3 mm pointed to the developer roller, which is part of the cartridge on that model.